# Mean stack website loads very slow on server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I have problem to find out why my mean stack website load very slow.

I have debug the problem and removed unnecessary css and javascript files but still it gets around 9-12 seconds in page load.

In my home page i m loading all the contents with text message and media message but if there is no contents then still it takes long time to load page.

i have doubts that it takes time because

1. i have call api for check session on angular controller load.
2. fetch all users list on angular controller load.
3. fetch category list on angular controller load.
4. i have given that controller scope in whole body tag so it is ok??
5. i have all node modules locally in my project.

So Please help me to debug my problem in right direction where i m going wrong??

Comment: Hey did you try any of the website performance tool to test your webpage. What is the response time you get when you try any of the tool? You can use [WebPagetest](https://www.webpagetest.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Angular and node both are good but all that matters is your application architecture.

1. Angular will take to load the data when your data is big,
   make sure your all calculation should be in back end so your front will take lesser time to put all data on html.
2. Angular will have to detect {{}} this to see calculations and expressions to put data in it.
3. And in case of back end, your logic and calculations should be in lesser code.
4. Keep this in mind, lesser the code faster your calculation, so be precious
5. Avoid complex coding
6. And lesser your api hits so angular will wait for lesser time to have data and put it all on html.
7. But in some cases, your PC and OS matters.